# Blockquote with shadow effect

Tags: css

I would like to make some changes to my current blockquote. This is my current code:

```
Css:

blockquote.style2 {
background:#e9e2d0;
margin-left: 50px;
padding-left: 15px;
border-left:4px solid #e85e4c;
}

HTML:

<blockquote class="style1">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
</blockquote>
```

I would like to have the red border on "top" (instead of the left) and add the shadow effect #2 that is showing in here: http://www.paulund.co.uk/creating-different-css3-box-shadows-effects . This is the code for the box shadow:

```
Css:
.box h3{
text-align:center;
position:relative;
top:80px;
}
.box {
width:70%;
height:200px;
background:#FFF;
margin:40px auto;
}


.effect2
{  position: relative;   }

.effect2:before, .effect2:after
  {     z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  max-width:300px;
  background: #777;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
.effect2:after   {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(3deg);
 transform: rotate(3deg);
 right: 10px;
 left: auto;
}

HTML:
<div class="box effect2">
<h3>Effect 2</h3>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciate it! Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to apply the CSS to your `blockquote`? Quite simply, change `border-left` to `border-top` and add `effect2` and `style2` to your class attribute.

Comment: Hi Chris, I don't know much about coding and css....I'm learning. If you could help me with the code I would appreciate it. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

With exactly what you provided for me, here's what you need to do to add just the shadow effect and switch the border to the top.

CSS

```
<style>
blockquote.style2 {
  background: #e9e2d0;
  margin-left: 50px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border-top: 4px solid #e85e4c;

  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
}
</style>
```

HTML

```
<blockquote class="style2">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
</blockquote>
```

Comment: Hi Jonsuh, but the shadow is not the same as the "effect #2" from the link: http://www.paulund.co.uk/creating-different-css3-box-shadows-effects

Comment: I kept trying and finally got it! Thanks anyway for your help!